# How to put score in label on second screen after NSTimer?

Tags: objective-c

I have a file (.m) wich is counting the clicks on a button

```
counter=counter +1;
        count.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",counter];
```

After a NSTimer a new screen appears (a new .m / .h / .xib file) but i want the score (clicks on button) in a label on the **new** screen.

On the **first** screen header file i'm doing:

```
IBOutlet UILabel *count;
```

but after the NStimer countdown i want to display to score on the **new** screen (screen 2)

Does anyone know how i can do this?

Need some more information? Please ask me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your randomMainVoid: action set the property of the label before you push the second view.
I don't know the name of your secondViewController and what you named the label in the secondViewController, so I can't give you exact code here.

Can you tell me what those names are and I will post the code here for you.

You should always name your ViewControllers with a Capital letter like Score, not score. But in either case:

```
Score *scoreView = [[Score alloc]initWithNibName:@"Score" bundle:nil];
 [scoreView.count setText:count.text];  //Replace this with the text you want to pass
[self presentModalViewController:scoreView animated:YES];
```

Or if your using a NavigationController you could push the view onto the stack:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:scoreView animated:YES];
```

Comment: My first file is called; itouchers.h/m and second file score.h/m. label in second file (score) is called  `IBOutlet UILabel *count;`

Comment: Score .h: `int counter;
@interface score : UIViewController {
    
    IBOutlet UILabel *count;
}
@end`

Comment: Also make sure to import "Score.h" in the itouchers.h or.m

Comment: Thanks but how do i connect this with a label in my score file? And http://cl.ly/3t170l3B0e332J0n0O36

Comment: Yes i imported the score.h :)

Comment: [scoreView.count setText:count.text]; this line will set the label of the scoreView label, if the labels name is: count and the text to set is: count.text. Make sure you don't re-set the label in the ScoreViewController or it will overwrite it when the view loads. You named both labels count?

Comment: Men this is weird stil an error.. :S [scoreView.counter setText:count.text];
, [scoreView.count setText:count.text]; huh?

Comment: Yes label in score.h is called count also in itouchers score.h file: `int counter;
@interface score : UIViewController {
    
    IBOutlet UILabel *count;
}



@end
`

Comment: replace Score with score. Looks like the name is lowercase.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6449/discussion-between-nathan-and-hubert-kunnemeyer)

Answer (score 0):

So, how are you initializing your timer? I assume you are using something like...

`timerWithTimeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:`

This method takes a selector, which is called when the timer expires/fires. In this method you should be displaying your view and you can pass the count to the new view you are creating. When your view loads you can set the count to a label on the view.

Comment: randomMain = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(randomMainVoid)
                                                    userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

Answer (score 0):

Just give your second view controller an initializer like:

```
- (id)initWithScoreText:(NSString*)scoreText {
    if ((self = [super initWithNibName:@"MyNibName" bundle:nil])) {
        scoreLabelText = [scoreText copy];
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //set the text of the label
    scoreLabel.text = scoreLabelText;
}

- (void) dealloc {
    //release the string since we copied it
    [scoreLabelText release];

    [super dealloc];
}
```

Then in your first view controller, you would do something like:

```
SecondViewController* newController = [[[SecondViewController alloc] initWithScoreText:count.text] autorelease];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:newController animated:YES];
```

Edit:  updated based on feedback from Paul.s.

Comment: Thanks Aroth but one question 'SecondViewController newController' what is 'newController'? I replaced 'SecondViewController' to the name of the name of the second file 'score' but i dont get 'newController'

Comment: 'newController' is just the variable name.  It's the view controller for the second screen that you want to show.  But I should have had a `*` in there as well.  Like `SecondViewController* newController = ...`, try that.

Comment: score* newController = [[[score alloc] initWithScoreText:count.text] autorelease];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:newController animated:YES]; is giving me: http://cl.ly/1M3C453k0Y270l473p0S

Comment: You need to declare the `initWithScoreText:` method in your 'score.h' file.  Just add `- (id)initWithScoreText:(NSString*)scoreText;` to the `@interface` (and make sure you implement the method in 'score.m', if you haven't already).

Comment: in the first file called 'itouch.m' i did: ` score* newController = [[score alloc] initWithScoreText:count.text]; `
        `[self.navigationController pushViewController:newController animated:YES]; and in the second file 'score.m' i did - (id)initWithScoreText:(NSString*)scoreText {
    if ((self = [super initWithNibName:@"MyNibName" bundle:nil])) {
        count.text = scoreText;
    }
    
    return self;
} ` but how i can connect the label? Hmm i dont get this one (grrr stupid me)

Comment: And if i use the code the back button doesn't work anymore i use `self.title = @"Game over"; ` and this is what happend : http://cl.ly/2W2s1f3K1C1L1I3s2u35

Comment: @aroth Surely that's far too early to call `scoreLabel.text = ...` it won't even be created until the view is loaded?

Comment: @Paul.s - You could be right, though I'm not in a position to actually test the code right now.  In any case, if the controller had a field like `scoreLabelText` that got set in init, and then code in `viewDidLoad` that did `scoreLabel.text = scoreLabelText`, that should work, no?

Comment: Yup that is how I would do it. The requirement for it to be in the `init` method would be more a convenience than a necessity I would say unless of course the class simply wouldn't function without that string being provided upfront